# Is there a way to change the 'Auto Number' Name of Standard Objects?

Tags: apex, standard-objects, auto-number, standard-field, name

We are using Salesforce Maps to schedule Visits to Retail Stores.  We've noticed that the Visit records that are created are using an Auto Number as the Name, giving values such as "00000564" when we review Related Records or List Views.  These numerical values are not useful in determining visits, I would prefer being able to use a formula including the Retail Store name and the Planned Date of the visit.  However, Visits are a Standard Object, and Name is a Standard Field that is set to Auto Number.

Is there any way to adjust the naming convention of these records?

Comment: [Formula field](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields) on Visits

Comment: @identigral, I am aware of Formula fields, but can't seem to adjust the Data Type of the Name

Comment: ...thus formula field. See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @identigral
"The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem."
My problem is: The name field is what is referenced in lists, and on Related Related Records, at the top of the record page.

Are you implying that I can change what is referenced in all those places, instead of needing to change the Name?

Comment: Your problem is _...determining visits_ . That's a report at best and list view at worst. Yes, list views can show just about any field, including a formula field. Related Records - it depends.

Comment: @identigral My problem is that my clients would like the Name of the record to not be a number.  Hence the question "Is there a way"

Comment: No, your clients want to determine visits. They might be insisting on a technical solution (the Y in XY), c;'est la vie. You'll have to educate them on their choices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149307/discussion-between-amtrying-and-identigral).